# How to force angular material 2 sidenav content from bottom

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

have been trying several places in css to override existing sidenav component in angular material 2

```
mat-sidenav-container {
   background: white;
   bottom: 0px !important; /* <---- no help */
}
mat-sidenav {
   width: 300px;
   height: 500px;


   padding-left:20px;   /* Not sure why content goes out of range*/
   bottom: 0px !important; /* <---- no help */
}
```

[Trying to make sidenav content start from bottom in this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/eGnr8iQzXj7SmStuRr2H?p=preview)
but I can't seem to override anything in this component provided by angular material 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this, there is no need to override the .mat classes style. Use the following css to place the content at bottom.

Side-nav content:

```
 <div class="inner-content" id="botNav" mat-list-item>
    <button mat-button *ngFor="let app of apps">{{ app }}</button>
 </div>
```

Css to place the content:

```
.inner-content{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/GZroFhKjuXhtYu7bvgPK?p=preview